# request.post() in nodejs request library doesn't work for some urls

Tags: node.js, request

I have found request.post() in https://github.com/request/request doesn't work for some urls.

I have narrowed to this sample code:

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8080/message';
request.post(url,{json:true},function(err,res,body){console.log('Called');});
```

This one outputs "Called" on console.
However,

```
var url = 'http://localhost:8080/message/test';
request.post(url,{json:true},function(err,res,body){console.log('Called');});
```

Nothing is output on the screen.

These are all 404 pages on the server established in 8080 port.

What's the problem? Is this some problem in request library or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: did you create the route for this?

Comment: Are you sure that the server is sending a response?

Comment: @MuhammadAli They are all 404 pages and I expect some err throwed (This means callback being called). Actually this doesn't work either when using some real routes (returning data). To mscdex It looks like the server is not sending the request at all.